# I think I need an adapter pattern here, but I seem to be repeating method implementation details

Tags: java, design-patterns, adapter

You can see below that I have two concrete classes that can share almost all of the implementation details already provided through an abstract class. They each only have to implement 2-3 methods themselves. However, ImplOne also implements from InterfaceTwo, which has an additional 1-2 methods to implement. I don't want to have to provide the exact same implementation details in ImplOne as I do in AbstractImpl, but what I have here currently does not seem right. In the adapter pattern, from the examples I've seen, the implementation details do seem to be duplicated for the interfaces being adapted.

```
       InterfaceOne
         /      \
InterfaceTwo  AbstractImpl
         \      /       \
          ImplOne      ImplTwo
```

Comment: Where is the duplication? I don't see why you have to duplicate implementations.

Comment: Isn't there something wrong with extending an abstract class that implements InterfaceOne, and then implementing InterfaceTwo, which also extends InterfaceOne? I don't know, but something seems wrong about that.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with that. It's just type information. The methods don't have to be re-implemented because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no problem with this scenario. ImplOne must implement all methods declared in interfaceOne or interfaceTwo unless already implemented by abstractImpl. implOne must also implement abstract methods from abstractImpl. As an exercise, I suggest creating an ImplOne with no methods and let the compiler tell you what methods need implementing.